# I am having trouble with my Class, not quite sure if I am writing the code correctly

Tags: java

I am writing a class for a project regarding the Titanic. The instructions say 
Passenger: Represents a passenger of the Titanic, with attributes (instance variables): 
Instance data:
status (an integer: 1, 2, 3, or 4, representing 1st, 2nd, 3rd class or crew
child (a boolean: true = child, false = adult) 
sex (a String: “male” or “female”)
survivor (a boolean: true/false indicating whether this passenger survived)

Here is my code currently, not sure if it is off or if I am putting things in the wrong place

```
//********************************************************************
//  Passenger.java       Author:
//
//  Represents passenger on Titanic.
//********************************************************************

import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Passenger
{
   int status;
   boolean child;
   String sex;
   boolean survivor;

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------
  //  Creates a new DVD with the specified information.
  //---------------------------------------------------------------- 
  public Passenger (int 1, int 2,int 3, int 4, boolean true, boolean          false, String m, String f)
  {
      1=1stclass;
      2=2ndclass;
      3=3rdclass;
      4=crew;
      true=child;
      false=adult;
      m=male;
      f=female;
  }

}
```

Comment: Is there a specific question here?

Comment: His question is whether is code is correct, to which the answer is a big *no*.

Comment: your constructor looks very very bad. it seems that you have no idea what are you doing.. First of all fix the parameters name of the constructor..

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to do this would be the following:

```
public class Passenger {
    int status;
    boolean child;
    String sex;
    boolean survivor;

    public Passenger (int status, boolean child, String sex, boolean survivor) {
        this.status = status;
        this.child = child;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.survivor = survivor;
    }
}
```

but since you probably do not know what `this` means, let us just come up with new variable names instead:

```
public class Passenger {
    int status;
    boolean child;
    String sex;
    boolean survivor;

    public Passenger (int c_status, boolean c_child, String c_sex, boolean c_survivor) {
        status = c_status;
        child = c_child;
        sex = c_sex;
        survivor = c_survivor;
    }
}
```

A constructor is called when an instance of this class is created by for example

```
new Passenger(2, true, "female", false)
```

after which the constructor will take these four values, and do what it is supposed to do. In our case, it will take these values and assign them to the four fields `status`, `child`, `sex`, and `survivor`.

To be able to tell the constructor to do this, we give these parameters a name (so we can refer to them) - in our example: `c_status`, etc. Then we tell the constructor to take the value of `c_status` and put it into `status` where it is saved until the object gets destroyed.

I suggest you open a Java-book and read through it. I am writing this answer mostly to give you a quick-fix.

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor is incorrect

for constructor parameters you can't use actual values, you must use names for them. It must be:

```
`public Passenger( int status, boolean child, String sex, boolean survivor){
   this.status = status;
   this.child = child;
   this.sex = sex;
   this.survivor = survivor;
}
//you also can add setters and getters for your class attributes
public void setStatus(int status) {
   this.status = status;
}
public int getStatus() {
   return status;
}
//so you can create another setters and getters for all your attributes`
```

Now try to replace your constructor with this one.